# validate age with Function

Tags: java

Hello I'm trying to validate an input from Scanner and I create the following function in Java but it doesn't work, what should be my error??

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int edad;

        System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
            edad= sc.nextInt();

            validarEdad(edad);

    }

    public static int validarEdad(int valor){
        while(valor<18 && valor >70){

            System.out.println("Intente de nuevo...");

            System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
            valor= sc.nextInt();

        }
        return valor;

    }


}
```

Comment: `valor<18 && valor >70` can never be true.

Answer (score 1):

Your boolean statement in your `validarEdad()` method is slightly wrong.

Instead of `while(valor<18 && valor>70)`,

I think you mean `while(valor<18 || valor>70)`.

The mistake here being the boolean logic of the `&&`(and) and `||`(or) operators.
You don't want the age to be less than 18 ***AND*** greater than 70. You want to it to be less than 18 ***OR*** greater than 70.

Here's some further reading on operators:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Congratulations. You got some reputation within just a very few days. Many newbies  claim that to be impossible in this oh so hostile community. Please take the [tour], just as something of a good-luck-charm.

Comment: @Yunnosch I just did so. Very interesting that mods are created via the scoring system.

Comment: Mods, as in diamond moderators, are created by voting (i.e. election voting, not up-/down voting). Privileges are granted via reputation rewards. I like the system. Welcome by the way.